# Can't access some hidden Excel rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was given an Excel spreadsheet which I opened with Excel 2016. It seems to have some rows which are not visible. In the screenshot below, you can see the row numbers jump from 2 to 338 and from 343 to 375. There is data in these rows that I want to access. I tried selecting the entire spreadsheet and choosing Unhide, or selecting the entire spreadsheet and setting all row heights to 20 pixels, but these rows won't appear.

What is going on, and how can I get all rows to appear?

[image: Excel worksheet rows that skip numbers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried unhiding the rows programmatically, to see if that works?  You can do it with a VBA macro like this:

```
Cells.Select
Range(Cells.Address).Activate
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Comment: @KAE Disregard my answer... I didn't see yours until after mine was posted.

Comment: I always like a programming solution so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled across [this answer](https://wmfexcel.com/2015/05/23/where-are-filter-drop-downs/) which allowed me to see the missing rows. I cleared the Filter, and all rows appeared. [I am answering my own question in the hopes of helping another person with this issue, but will delete the question if that's more appropriate.]